# Prove that a partition cut of a graph is a disjoint union of its minimal edge cuts

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, connectedness

Let $X$ and $Y$ form a partition of the vertices of a connected simple graph $G$. The partition cut $ \langle X, Y \rangle $ is the set of all edges that have one endpoint in $X$ and the other endpoint in $Y$. How to prove that $ \langle X, Y \rangle $ is a  disjoint union of minimal edge cuts of $G$?

My thought:

After deleting $ \langle X, Y \rangle $, let $ X_1 , \cdots, X_m $ be the connected components of $X$ and $ Y_1 , \cdots, Y_n $ be the connected components of $Y$ in $G - \langle X, Y \rangle$. For each $i$ and $j$, let $ \langle X_i, Y_j \rangle $ be the set of all edges that have one endpoint in $X_i$ and the other endpoint in $Y_j$.

By decomposing $ \langle X, Y \rangle $ into a disjoint union of $ \langle X_i, Y_j \rangle $ over $ 1 \leq i \leq m $ and $ 1 \leq j \leq n $, we see a "quotient structure" that looks like a bipartite graph. Intuitively, if $S$ is a minimal edge cut contained in $ \langle X, Y \rangle $, then either all $X$-endpoints of $S$ are in a single component $X_i$ or all $Y$-endpoints of $S$ are in a single component $Y_j$.

I don't know how to make my intuition into a rigorous proof. Could anyone help?